# XSLT: Aggregate child nodes data in parent

Tags: xml, xslt, lxml

Assume I have following node:

```
<parent>
  <child size="1" />
  <child size="2" />
  <child size="3" />
</parent>
```

What I'd like to get in the output document is average, min & max values of child sizes. I.e.

```
<parent min-size="1" max-size="3" avg-size="2" />
```

Is it possible to do using XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT extensions?

Comment: Well, if you want to use EXSLT have you not checked its functions like http://exslt.org/math/functions/max/index.html?

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for pointing at the documentation. I kind of missed that it actually has helpful samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using [math:max()](http://exslt.org/math/functions/max/index.html) and [math:min()](http://exslt.org/math/functions/min/index.html)...

**XSLT 1.0** (stylesheet.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
  extension-element-prefixes="math">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <parent min-size="{math:min(child/@size)}" 
      max-size="{math:max(child/@size)}" 
      avg-size="{sum(child/@size) div count(child/@size)}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("stylesheet.xsl")

new_tree = tree.xslt(xslt)

print(etree.tostring(new_tree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

**Output**

```xml
<parent min-size="1" max-size="3" avg-size="2"/>
```

Comment: For some reason lxml doesn't work with curly braces. But if I change, say `min-size="{math:min(child/@size)}"` to `min-size="math:min(child/@size)"`, your solution works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @z4y4ts - Strange; the [AVTs](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) (curly braces) worked fine for me in python 3.6.5 and lxml 4.2.1. Glad you got it working though!